# Xpath&Xquery: Selecting and Returning XML elements with multiple complex tags

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0

I've recently been introduced to the wonderful world of XPath and XQuery. I've been able to construct some queries using logical operators but I'm stuck on a particular problem, which I can't seem to find a answer for. It involves attributes 'wrapped' around a tag.

I'm using Exide to search through an XML document and the structure doesn't look like anything I've seen while researching. It looks (something) like this:

```
<Report name="Report001">
    <ReportDetail name="SubSection1">
        <Properties>
            <tag name="bar">blue</tag>
            <tag name="bar2">green</tag>
            <tag name="bar3">yellow</tag>
            <tag name="bar4">white</tag>
        </Properties>
             <ReportItem detail1="some value" detail2="some value" detail3="some value" detail4="some value" detail5="some value">
                <item1>foo</item1>
                <item2>foo2</item2>
                <item3>foo3</item3>
                <item4>foo4</item4>
                <item5>foo5</item5>
             </ReportItem>
     </ReportDetail>
     <ReportDetail name="SubSection2">
        <Properties>
            <tag name="bar">blue</tag>
            <tag name="bar2">green</tag>
            <tag name="bar3">pink</tag>
            <tag name="bar4">lime</tag>
        </Properties>
            <ReportItem detail1="some value2" detail2="some value2"detail3="some value2" detail4="some value2" detail5="some value2">
                <item1>foo</item1>
                <item2>foo2</item2>
                <item3>foo3</item3>
                <item4>foo4</item4>
                <item5>foo5</item5>
            </ReportItem>
      </ReportDetail>
</Report>
```

What I'm trying to search (and count) for and then return in a query is those *ReportDetail names* where

1. tag name matches bar2
2. the tag itself contains (or equals) green
3. and item3 equals foo3

I've tried variations of the following: 
For the first two parts of the query the following queries have produced

```
count(//Properties/tag[@name='bar2'] | /tag[. ,'green']))

count//Properties/tag[@name='bar2'][. ,'green']))

count(//Properties[contains(@name, "bar2")])
```

for the third part of the query I think it should look like one of these:

```
and //ReportItem[item3=foo3])        

//ReportItem[item3=foo3]
```

So the entire query would look like:

```
count(//Properties/tag[@name='bar2'] | /tag[. ,'green'] and /ReportItem[item3=foo3)
```

Comment: Please provide well-formed XML documents (close all elements!) don't have those helping you out fix the input before they can do so. Also: what did you try, where exactly are you stuck? What's the expected output for the query you're looking for on the input data you provided? Please have a look at [ask] to see what should be included in a good question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, updated as requested.

Comment: Your XPath expressions have `//HostProperties` but your XML input has no elements of that name.

Comment: updated the expressions, thanks.

Comment: Most of your xpath expressions are not even valid and the ones that are valid have any little relevance to the example xml document.  With the greatest repect, I think its clear that you dont have the basic understanding of xpath. I suggest you check out http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp which will offer you a step-by-step tutorial after which you'll probably be able to work this out yourself.

Comment: It is still unclear what elements you want to count. Are you after the reports that match the conditions? A good starting point would not to count the result elements, better select them first and verify you're matching the correct elements. Wrapping the query in a  `count(...)` function call is easy then.

Comment: I'd like to return the ReportDetail name (e.g. SubSection2)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the problem very precisely. Let's suppose that when you say:

I'm trying to search (and count) for and then return in a query is those ReportDetail names where

tag name matches bar2
the tag itself contains (or equals) green
and item3 equals foo3

what you actually mean is:

I'm trying to return the names of those ReportDetail elements where all of the following conditions are true:

- there is a child Properties with a child tag whose name matches bar2
- there is a child Properties with a child tag (not necessarily the same one) whose string value is green
- there is a child ReportItem with a child item3 equals foo3

then that would be

```
//ReportDetail[Properties/tag[@name='bar2'] and Properties/tag[.='green'] and ReportItem/item3[.='foo3]]
```

It seems to me that your real problem is not in coding the XPath, but in expressing logically and unambiguously what information you actually want to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

your Xpath has incorrect syntax. I think, it should be:

```
count(//Properties/tag[@name='bar2'] | //tag[.='green'] | //ReportItem[item3='foo3'])
```